# Getting unknown characters between each letter when reading uploaded CSV on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I'm trying to upload a CSV file, read its contents and import that data into a database, but apparently I'm getting some kind of bug where an unknown character shows between each character.

This is my code:

```
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $fileName = $file->getRealPath();
    $file = fopen($fileName, "r");

    $i = 0;
    while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

        if ($i == 0){
            $i++;
            continue;
        }
        echo print_r($column);$i++;    
    }

    fclose($file);
```

This is what I get from print_r:

[image]

Any ideas on what could it be? I've tried opening the CSV with encoding UTF8 and UTF16 but I still have this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the actual csv-file?

Comment: @ege it's a simple CSV: 
4;Pregunta 1 lorem ipsum;1
4;Pregunta 2;2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's `\0` char that some system appends. Check with `ord($string[0])`

You can simply do `str_replace("\0", '', $string)`

Or try some regex replace: `preg_replace('/[^\w\d-.,\s]/', '', $string)`